# Manual set the height of UILable with autolayout

Tags: ios, uilabel, autolayout, constraints

There's a UIlabel with dynamical height in my custom cell, the height value is calculated through the method:

```
- (CGRect)boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize)size options:(NSStringDrawingOptions)options attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes context:(NSStringDrawingContext *)context
```

Then I invoke the following method by passing the value calculated before:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

but, the problem is that I can't simple set `label.frame = newFrame` to fit its content because of autolayout.

And, i don't wanna set many constraints to the elements in my storyboard. What I really need is just one single line code like `lable.constraint.height = newHeight`, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Set constraint to yourlabel.

```
[yourlabel setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

[yourlabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO]; 

NSLayoutConstraint *constraintHeight = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:yourlabel
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                           toItem:nil
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                       multiplier:1.0
                                                                         constant:newheight];

[yourlabel addConstraints:@[constraintHeight]];
```

Comment: It's not working for me, seems can't add new constraint. BTW, I add this code when do cell configuration stuff.

Comment: try adding it in your custom cell class